# Is jRebel even needed in Intellij?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, jrebel

I am now able to auto incrementally compile on save in my Java EE project that is running on a Websphere server.

I **unistalled jRebel** because I had issues starting the server suddenly, and noticed that now that Intellij is auto compiling I am **also able to see** the changes "almost" effectively ( **slower than** in Eclipse )

So, is jRebel even needed in Intellij? My **settings** for Websphere can be seen in **the picture below**. Note that I have only added **one Ear file**, and it is not the exploded version, still this is working. Is jrebel still in play here someway? jrebel.xml's are still present.

[image]

Comment: most likely, in server.xml you still have -javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar left and as you said rebel.xml is still there, then you are running with JRebel and removing the plugin from IDE doesn't actually change anything, as if you set JRebel up manually

Comment: Hmm.. Where is this server.xml ? Usually with Intellij though, you start the server, with a specific jRebel icon. Start with Jrebel, and then you have the start server. Now I am just using the start server. Anyway, it is not a biggie...

Comment: it's somewhere deep in WAS configurations. Just search for server.xml inside the profile folder that you execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears, as if jRebel is still running, although the plugin is uninstalled. I can see jRebel outputs in the logs. 
Unsure why really, but it must be why things are running this smooth.

So the answer is no for now.